# Laravel 7 on Ubuntu 20.04 with NGINX - Images in storage/protected/images directory return 404 when accessed via url

Tags: nginx, laravel-7, ubuntu-20.04

I just moved the app from the local environment to the test/production server.

Everything workes with AWS drive, but when changing to the local drive a.e `storage/protected/images` where my images are stored, I get `error 404` on all images from local drive.

All routes are present and all controllers are in place as well. The interesting part of it all is that the downloadable files that I also store in `storage/protected/files` work just fine and I can download them without any problem whatsoever.

here is my `ImageViewController`

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Client;

```
use App\Exceptions\ErrorPageException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ImageViewController extends Controller
{
    public function getMainImage($name)
    {
        if(file_exists(storage_path().'/app/protected/images/'.$name)){
            $image = storage_path().'/app/protected/images/'.$name;
        }else{
            throw new ErrorPageException(404);
        }
        return response()->file($image);
    }

    public function getImage($type, $name)
    {
        if(file_exists(storage_path().'/app/protected/images/'.$type.'/'.$name)){
            $image = storage_path().'/app/protected/images/'.$type.'/'.$name;
        }else{
            throw new ErrorPageException(404);
        }
        return response()->file($image);
    }

}
```

and the direct URL I use to access the image is `example.com/images/image.png`

I suspect that this error has something to do with my nginx setup, unless I am wrong.

Please share your thoughts and help me if you can.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, the nginx setup was causing the issue so here is what I had to do to sort this all out:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;
    root /var/www/laravel/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

the source: [How to Install and Configure Laravel with LEMP on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-laravel-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-18-04)